# PyGTK/Glade keep button size standard

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I have a simple pygtk/glade window with a menu and a 3x3 grid. Each row of the grid consists on: two labels and a button.

When the Window is resized, the labels holds the same font size, but the buttons get resized, and they could become HUGE if the windows gets very big.

How could I manage to keep my buttons with the same size always (the "standar" size of a button, just like they are when the interface is just opened) no matter if the Window is resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set the `fill` and `expand` parameters of the Buttons to False (uncheck them in the Glade interface).

You would also want to put each button at the center of a 3x3 `GtkTable`, so it will appear centered and not aligned at the top of the cell